# Splitting A String Into An Array Of Words To Be Called Again

Tags: java, arrays, string, computer-science, jgrasp

**This is my code so far below**

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class USconstitution   
{
  public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
  {
     Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("constitution.txt"));
     int x = 0;
     int keyword1 = 0;
     Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter a word from the keyboard");
     String input = keyboard.next();
     while(inFile.hasNext())
     {
        String word = inFile.next();
        x++;
        if(input.equalsIgnoreCase(word))
           keyword1++;
     }
     //System.out.println("\n" + x);
     System.out.println("The constitution has " + x + " words");
     System.out.println("The first keyword shows up " + keyword1 + " times in the  

     constitution");
  }
}
```

**THE OUTPUT SO FAR** =

Enter a word from the keyboard

President

The constitution has 4610 words

The first keyword shows up 20 times in the constitution

---

My goal for this program is to search through a text file that has been given to me which contains the US Constitution.

The first part simply counts how many words are in the text file, the next bit that I am trying to do is allow people to search for certain keywords and have it search the text file and say how many times that word shows up.

I was thinking of having the prompt ask what keywords the user wishes to enter and have it use the split method to create each word as an individual string and search for that in the file then output how many times it appears. Although I am not so sure how to go about this, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Do you want a total for each of the words in the list separately or an accumulative total? i.e. Keywords: "some" "key" "words" Output: "some" = 10, "key" = 5, "words" = 5. Or total = 20?

Comment: In a way yes, I was thinking of taking a single sentence with keywords separated with spaces such as i.e "Enter keywords separated by a space" and the user would enter something such as, "President JAVA writing". Three different words, I was wondering if I could take those three words from one string and split it into different ones, then see if they show up in the text file and output for example "President shows up 20 times in the file"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{       
    String text = "the quick brown fox jumps fox fox over the lazy dog brown";
    String[] textArray = text.split(" ");
    String[] keysToSearch = {"the", "fox", "dog"};
    int count = 0;
    System.out.println(text);

    for(String key: keysToSearch)
    {                       
        for(String s : textArray)
        {
            if(key.equals(s))
            {
                count++;
            }               
        }
        System.out.println("Count of ["+key+"] is : "+count);
        count=0;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
the quick brown fox jumps fox fox over the lazy dog brown
Count of [the] is : 2
Count of [fox] is : 3
Count of [dog] is : 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the assistance, I had no idea you could conjure up such a method!

Answer (score 0):

Take the code that does the check out of the main method and put it in a separate method that takes a single keyword as a parameter. Then you can split the input string given from the console using

```
String[] keywords = input.split(" "); // will split at spaces
```

Then all you have to do is loop through all of the keywords in your array

```
for(int  i = 0; i < keywords.length; i++){

    yourCountMethod(keywords[i]);

}
```

This is just the general idea, obviously you will have to change the code to suit.

Hope that helps :)